# WebChromeClient Microphone, Camera, audio,video capture permission

Tags: android, ios, camera, microphone, webchromeclient

I am using WebChromeClient in an Android application to access a third party website. The site is getting loaded on my WebChromeClient, but I am facing the following issues -

1. When I am clicking on any link it is getting redirected to the installed browser.But I need to open all the subsequent links/pages in the same WebChromeClient.
2. The 3rd party website which I am trying to access requires permission to the microphone as well as camera, and I have already given those permissions in my app but still it is showing permission error when that 3rd party page is getting loaded.

I also need to create an IOS application (in swift) having same requirement. Please provide me working samples code (if any one already have).

If there is ant cordova hybrid sample application is available with the same functionality Please provide me.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Please help me, I need to implement it ASAP.

Comment: Looks like No Solution is available...Strange!!!